# Auto generating sequence diagram for C++ code linux environment

Tags: c++, linux

Are there any eclipse plugin available to auto generate sequence diagram for **C++** code running in the linux environment?  Please let me know the details. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use eclipse with [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org) with [Trace2UML](http://trace2uml.tigris.org/doxygen.htm).

Comment: hi dacwe,
With doxygen we can create class diagrams. I am not sure whether we can create sequence diagram using the same. would you please elaborate on how to create sequence diagram using doxygen?

Comment: Added link to Trace2UML. Is this even suffisant for you?

Comment: *Trace2UML* appears to be converting `\msc` markup into a graphical representation. It doesn't auto-generate the `\msc` markup from either static code analysis or runtime tracing. Am I missing anything?